# Cannot install imblearn to use SMOTE

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, oversampling, imblearn

I have been trying to install imblearn to use SMOTE, and I thought it was successful, but when I type in this in my Jupyter Notebook `from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE`, I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'SMOTE'`. Do you know why this might be the case? I used the following command to download imblearn `conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn` and got the download confirmation once it finished.

[image: Smote Installation]

Comment: Please add the full import error message as text. Images of code and output are less helpful.

Comment: Here is the import statement I wrote: from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE and here is the error ImportError: cannot import name 'SMOTE'. I guess I included the screenshot to show the imbalanced-learn package was downloaded using Conda.

Comment: Please add all relevant stuff to the question itself.

Comment: In other words: don't put information important to answer the question into the comments only.

Comment: Okay, my apologies. I added the ImportError part to the question now. Do you have any suggestions about how to deal with this? Thanks!